# how to Query a very complex array MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, crud

mongodb data:

```
{
    'setting': [{
            'asin': 'b0dfhuyd',
            'campaigns': [{
                    'id': 48476,
                    'adgroups': [{
                            'id': 126029,
                            'name': 'auto 1'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 240147,
                            'name': 'auto low bid'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id': 20855,
                    'adgroups': [{
                            'id': 23709,
                            'name': 'broad 1'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 25788,
                            'name': 'precise'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 16918,
                            'name': 'broad low bid'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id': 37591,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 25022,
                        'name': 'Ad group 1'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'asin': 'b02343',
            'campaigns': [{
                    'id': 13921,
                    'adgroups': [{
                            'id': 24363,
                            'name': 'auto1'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 21425,
                            'name': 'low bid'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id': 57847,
                    'adgroups': [{
                            'id': 12414,
                            'name': 'broad 1'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 20222,
                            'name': 'precise'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 17904,
                            'name': 'broad 低价'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id': 25353,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 52652,
                        'name': 'Ad group 1'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'asin': 'b02vgfg',
            'campaigns': [{
                    'id': 13415,
                    'adgroups': [{
                            'id': 14357,
                            'name': 'auto 1'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 22646,
                            'name': 'low bid'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id': 92883,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 15712,
                        'name': 'Ad group 1'
                    }]
                },
                {
                    'id': 11764,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 25707,
                        'name': 'Ad group 1'
                    }]
                },
                {
                    'id': 25965,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 91682,
                        'name': 'broad22'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'asin': 'b0dhfgd',
            'campaigns': [{
                    'id': 60169,
                    'adgroups': [{
                            'id': 33458,
                            'name': 'Ad group 1'
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 148198,
                            'name': 'dhdb'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id': 35782,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 102206,
                        'name': 'Ad group 1'
                    }]
                },
                {
                    'id': 22602,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 9593,
                        'name': 'category'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'asin': 'b0bdujh',
            'campaigns': [{
                    'id': 19066,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 20784,
                        'name': 'ghdghj'
                    }]
                },
                {
                    'id': 77530,
                    'adgroups': [{
                        'id': 270461,
                        'name': 'ffff666'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the structure of amazon sponsored products advertisement. **'setting'** include several asins' advertisement setting documents. **'campaigns'** include some **'adgroups'**.
**asin** is the unique id for product. **campaign** and **adgroup** are advertising hierachy.

now I want to query the exact name of specific adgroup by asin,campaigns->id,adgroups->id fields.
For example: Given asin='b0dfhuyd',campaigns.id=48476,adgroups.id=126029, how to get the adgroups.name?
I've tried with $elemMatch, but somehow I didn't make it

Comment: does that solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

1. first match is required to not to deal with lot of data.
2. but as matching will return you whole set of document along with nested one. we have to go and find out exact element from each array.

```js
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'setting': {
        '$elemMatch': {
          'asin': 'b0dfhuyd', 
          'campaigns': {
            '$elemMatch': {
              'id': 48476, 
              'adgroups': {
                '$elemMatch': {
                  'id': 126029
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'setting': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$setting', 
          'as': 's', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$s.asin', 'b0dfhuyd'
            ]
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': '$setting'
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'campaign': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$setting.campaigns', 
          'as': 'c', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$c.id', 48476
            ]
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': '$campaign'
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'adGroup': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$campaign.adgroups', 
          'as': 'a', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$a.id', 126029
            ]
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'name': {
        '$arrayElemAt': [
          '$adGroup.name', 0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks so much. I think it is so complex. for loop will better agree with me